# how can I switch between ip addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip-address

How can I switch between IP addresses on Ubuntu 18.4. My network card has several IP addresses. How can I, for example, change my IP address automatically every 10 seconds?

Comment: You may not have to do anything. You can see the `valid_lft` and `preferred_lft` count down in the output of `ip address list`, setting up reasonable values is the job of the mechanism that assigned the IP addresses (your router, probably).

Comment: Valid lifetime and preferred lifetime of each is forever